# My Angular app only works with a certain syntax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm following a thinkster tutorial on angular and rails. The tutorials says to make the app like this...

`angular.module('flapperNews', [])`

with the controllers and factories like this...

`.config([...
 .controller([...
 .factory([...`

and so on. However it only works when I do this...

`var flapperNews = angular.module('flapperNews', [])`

with the controllers and factories like this...

`flapperNews.config([...
 flapperNews.controller([...
 flapperNews.factory([...`

Is there a short answer for this? Is the tut wrong or am I doing something wrong.
Here is the tut link 
https://thinkster.io/angular-rails#introduction

I haven't started the rails part yet, just wanted to know why it breaks.

Here are the two codepens... 
This one works as described above.
http://codepen.io/MrNagoo/pen/regKgM

This one fails and gives errors, although it's how i'm being directed to write the code...

http://codepen.io/MrNagoo/pen/regKEM

Comment: I would like to see a bit more Code but normally you have to inject Controllers in your module: `angular.module('flapperNews', ['flapperCtrl', 'flapperSrv'])`. Perhaps this helps.

Comment: I've made a couple codepens.

Comment: @MrNagoo The 2nd pen works just as well. The only problem is, you're putting `;` after each controller/factory/whatever, so you get a syntax error. Also, there's a missing `$stateProvider` in the `config` function. Same pen, cleared up: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNRBbW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `;` before doing the next `.config` this terminate the statement. You need to chain the components.

`angular.module("app",[])
         .config()
         .controller()
         .service();`

here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNVBxK?editors=1111) with the working code

But you should definettly follow John Papa's style guide

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at John Papa's style guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1

You create your module as you said:

```
angular.module('flapperNews', [])
```

And you add a controller/factory/config/whatever like:

```
angular
    .module('flapperNews')
    .config(config)

function config() { ... }
```

Comment: It didn't answer what was happening but +1 for the awesome read.

Comment: Yeah, since it was just a couple of syntax errors I just answered it in a comment above, just what @adrianolsk said. :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that.